# How much load can Parse Server on Compute Engine instance handle

Tags: server, load-balancing, google-compute-engine, parse-server, google-cloud-platform

The server will run singly on one instance of compute engine. What could limit it's serving capacity and how much load can a single instance (4 vCPUs and 15GB Memory) handle.

Note : I've already looked at Kubernetes and even load-balancing multiple instances but accessing the database from multiple clients is a little too complicated for me right now. So please keep in mind if you're going to suggest containerisation, that I'm a beginner.

Any and all advice is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The serving capacity of the server depends on a number of factors, which includes the requests you receive from the clients, the additional applications running in it etc. For a 4 core CPU, as per [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#egress_throughput_caps) help center article, you will get a peak performance of 8Gb/s, which is good for a single instance. Since you are using a single parse server alone on the VM, it should work very well with the above-mentioned configuration.

A container is a tool for a developer. It contains all the dependencies and library which required to run/test a particular application in a container. The applications running in the container are easily portable.

There is [this](https://www.cio.com/article/2924995/software/what-are-containers-and-why-do-you-need-them.html) help center article which might give a precise idea of containers and its usage. While the Kubernetes Engine will help you to deploy/manage these containerized application.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Do you have an estimate of how many requests per second the single instance would be able to hande?

Comment: you'll be bound by node, IMHO, which is single threaded, on this kind of instance, I would recommend you use cluster mode, in order to leverage the multiple CPU cores.

Comment: Right. Thanks for that. Anyway for anyone interested, I performed some tests using JMeter on the above mentioned setup and with small write requests, the setup was able to handle 300 req/s (pretty good I'd say). Thanks everyone for the help!